# How to remove second class of html element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple span tags.
example:

```
<span class="name one"></span>
<span class="name two"></span>
<span class="name three"></span>
<span class="name four"></span>
```

how can i remove second class without using class name like span.classList.remove('three');
i just need something like span.classList.remove(1); to remove only second class from all span elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer

```
span.classList.remove(span.classList.item(1));
```